# Google Apps Script - Problem with simple if statement

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a simple 'If statement' that for some reason isn't able to properly find what data is in the cell it's referencing('Data' S26). It should contain either a 0 or a 1, but it doesn't seem to matter if I have a 0 or a 1 in the cell - either from a formula or directly, the following formula is always returning a "2". Completely new to this so probably something easy, but I can't seem to find the answer!

Thanks!

```
function InsertWinLoss(){
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  var gameSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Games');
  var currentRow = gameSheet.getLastRow();
  
  if (dataSheet.getRange('S26') =='1') {
      gameSheet.getRange(currentRow,3).setValue('1');
       } else if (dataSheet.getRange('S26') = '0') {
          gameSheet.getRange(currentRow,3).setValue('0');
} else { gameSheet.getRange(currentRow,3).setValue('2') }


  }
```

Comment: See official documentation. What object does `getRange()` return?

Comment: "Returns the range as specified in A1 notation or R1C1 notation."?  I'm guessing that's where the problem is, what should I be using instead?

Comment: Probably you need `getRange('S26').getValue()`

Comment: Yes, but if you look closer under "Return" in the documentation, you'll see what it means by `Range` type object.  There are different types of objects - number type, string type, range type, array type, etc. You cannot compare two different types. They'll have to be of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the original post might have been answered in comments, but for what it's worth:

- Call getValue() on the Range returned by the conditions in the `if` statements
- The `else if` condition has a syntax error; the expression uses the assignment operator `=`, rather than checking for equality `==`
- As originally written, the `setValue()` calls are writing 1, 0, or 2 as Strings, rather than Numbers; omit the '' if this isn't intended

Here's my two cents on rewriting the function to be a little more compact! Hope it's useful.

```
//By convention, functions should start lowercase
function insertWinLoss() {
  //Get Sheets
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  var gameSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Games');

  //Assign value of your win/loss cell to new variable
  var winLossValue = dataSheet.getRange('S26').getValue();

  //Set your output range
  var currentRow = gameSheet.getLastRow();
  var outputRange = gameSheet.getRange(currentRow, 3);

  //Now your if/else statements are a little more compact
  //and it's easier to change values like the win/loss cell or output column!
  if (winLossValue == 1) {
    outputRange.setValue('1');
  } else if (winLossValue == 0) {
    outputRange.setValue('0');
  } else {
    outputRange.setValue('2')
  }
}
```

Function should give desired result of writing 1, 0, or 2 to output range based on input to win/loss range.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations! IT Manager that is just doing this as a side project and forgot the very little bit of coding I learnt from free sites in the past. Much appreciated.